# net.iamyellow.gcmjs does not with SDK 6.3.0.GA for titanium appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

We migrated to an old `version(Ti 5.2.2).GA` to a new `version(Ti 6.3.0.GA)` of titanium Appcelerator.

When we run our app with latest `version(Ti 6.3.0.GA)` the `net.iamyellow.gcmjs` (0.2 & 0.3) module not supported.

My app is depends on `net.iamyellow.gcmjs` module.

Questions

1. Is there any latest version of `net.iamyellow.gcmjs` module to support for titanium `SDK Version 6.3.0.GA`?
2. If it is not there when will you release the new version of `net.iamyellow.gcmjs` module?
3. Is there any push notification module to support for both android and iOS app which are developed through titanium appcelerator?

Please, can please help me out.

Environments:

```
Operating System          = Mac OS X

Node.js Version           = 6.10.3

npm Version               = 3.10.10

Titanium CLI Version      = 5.0.14

Titanium SDK Version      = 6.3.0.GA

Axway Appcelerator Studio = 4.10.0
```

Comment: you can try https://github.com/SwanandMarathe/gcm.js It supports the Titanium SDK 6.0.x

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, to answer your question, iamyellow is no longer maintained and this has been the case for at least four years if I recall, with TiSDK 6.x there had been a an update on the v8 version which requires a rebuild of all android native modules if I recall correctly.

That being said, this should not be an issue as there already is a great module by the name of [ti.goosh](https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I think its no longer maintained but someone made a form and updated it, you can try github.com/SwanandMarathe/gcm.js

Answer (score 0):

For smaller modules like this one, you can update the module yourself to make it support a higher titanium SDK. In this case TheFuquan suggested an alternative module which hopefully fills your requirements, but for others where there might not be an alternative downloading the sourcecode from git and rebuilding the module for the newer sdk is usually pretty simple.

in this case i believe the only thing that needs to be changed is the "apiversion" to 3 in the manifest file of the module. Possibly the "architectures" property need to be updated in the manifest file aswell. Then you just build the module and you are good to go.